# Unable to select bits in Microsoft VC++ Inline ASM

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inline-assembly

Quite simple, really. I tried to use `EAX[31:26]` in my code, and was presented with the following error:

`error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'second operand'; found ':'`

And here's my code:

```
unsigned _EAX, _EBX, _ECX, _EDX ;
//LoadCPUID(EAX_CACHECONFIG, _EAX, _EBX, _ECX, _EDX);

__asm {
    mov EAX, EAX_CACHECONFIG ;
    mov ECX, 0x00000001 ;
    cpuid ;
    mov _EAX, EAX[31:26] ;
}

return _EAX;
```

Is it possible to select bits in the way shown above in MSVC's inline assembler? Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I can't recall ever seeing it anyway.

Comment: I'm curious - what assembler/compiler/tool have you used the `EAX[31:26]` notation with before?

Comment: Intel's AP-485. I'm fairly new to assembly, so I may have interpreted it incorrectly, but it states: ""The BIOS will use this function to determine the number of cores implemented in a specific physical processor package. To do this the BIOS must initially set the EAX register to 4 and the ECX register to 0 prior to executing the CPUID instruction. After executing the CPUID instruction, (EAX[31:26] + 1) contains the number of cores."

Comment: @Liam: I see - that notation is common in datasheets and other documents, but it's not assembly language syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using 0-based bit numbers with 0 being the least significant bit, you can get those top six bits simply by right-shifting `eax` 26 bits.

That gives you the upper six bits in the lower bit positions. If you want the result in the *same* bit positions, simply `and` it with `0xfc000000`.

If I've misunderstood your bit positions, you can still use shifts and the bitwise operators to get what you want, though the values (that you want to `and` with or shift by) may differ.

Based on your comment:

> After executing the CPUID instruction, (EAX[31:26] + 1) contains the number of cores.

The way you would get the number of cores is as follows:

```
...                  ; load up cpuid registers first
cpuid
shr    eax, 26       ; move bits 31:26 down to 5:0
inc    eax
...                  ; eax now contains the core count (1 thru 64).
```

Comment: The value of the number varies depending on the user's computer, so it may not or may not be zero-based.

Comment: @Liam, the value in those bits itself may change but your bit indexing won't. Bits are usually counted from high (eg, 31 = most significant) to low (0 = least significant). The value of those top six bits is irrelevant to that discussion, the values I was referring to was the amount to shift and the bitmasks to use. I'll clarify

Comment: I see. I'll test it ASAP and get back to you on it.